# How can I use mypy to type check a date that cannot be a datetime?

Tags: python, mypy

Let's say I have this function:

```
def subtract_dates(date1: datetime.date, date2: datetime.date):
    return date1 - date2
```

If I try to call `subtract_dates(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.now())` this will raise a TypeError because I'm trying to subtract a `datetime` object from a `date` object.

However, because datetime inherits from date (see for instance [this issue](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/2487)), MyPy does not raise an error on the above call to `subtract_dates`.

Is there a way to add a MyPy type hint that allows a date object but not a datetime object?

Comment: Removed `Python` tag as this is a question exclusive to `MyPy`.

Comment: @Felipe see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/287040. Python is a broad tag, and MyPy certainly falls under the broad tag of Python.

Answer (score 3):

I'd solve it by [function overloading](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading). Example:

```
import datetime
from typing import NoReturn, overload


@overload
def subtract_dates(date1: datetime.date, date2: datetime.datetime) -> NoReturn: ...

@overload
def subtract_dates(date1: datetime.datetime, date2: datetime.date) -> NoReturn: ...

@overload
def subtract_dates(date1: datetime.date, date2: datetime.date) -> datetime.timedelta: ...


# this is your original function implementation    
def subtract_dates(date1: datetime.date, date2: datetime.date):
    return date1 - date2
```

Now, subtracting dates is still allowed, while using `datetime` objects will be caught:

```
subtract_dates(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.now()).days
```

will give you an error

```
<string>:1: error: "NoReturn" has no attribute "days"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't really work, because mypy will happily strip type-specificity at lots of intermediary points.  Consider this if you have a function like this: `def launder_date(x: datetime.date) -> datetime.date: return x` then you can do `subtract_dates(launder_date(datetime.datetime.now()), datetime.date.today()).days` and receive no error.  This is really a bug that needs to be fixed in `mypy` itself: https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/3805

Comment: @Glyph The type specificity is stripped by loose typing of `launder_date()`, but can be fixed by using generics: `def launder_date(x: T) -> T: ...` with `T = TypeVar('T', bound=datetime.date)`.

Comment: I'm aware of what's happening :). If you *know* that `launder_date` is doing the wrong thing, you can fix it and have it do the right thing; but this kind of specificity-stripping lives all over the place, including in the standard library, so you have to be careful to never trip it up.  Which is kind of the whole point of having mypy in the first place? :)

Comment: @Glyph Ah, I get it - indeed, there's no way to circumvent that without changing the stdlib's `datetime` first.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to really do this definitively is to recreate all the stubs for `datetime` in such a way that it *pretends* not to be a subclass of `date`.  This is really tedious though.

That's why [I did it for you](https://pypi.org/project/datetype/) and put it into an open source library.

You can see some examples of how to use it [here](https://github.com/glyph/DateType/blob/b6828225d6c84857753f3271347abb7383367411/tryit.py).